# TypeError:__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, typeerror

I am currently running into this error.
I don't know what this error is caused by because I've declared the positional arguments `path2` and  `path3` already in my code but the error says that this two arguments missing.

**Error Message:**`TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'path2' and 'path3'`

**This is my code:**

```
import os
from tqdm import tqdm

from utils import SOS, EOS, UNK, process


class Corpus(object):
    def __init__(self, path, path2, path3, order, lower=False, max_lines=-1):
        self.order = order
        self.lower = lower
        self.max_lines = max_lines
        self.vocab = set()
        self.train = self.tokenize(os.path.join(path), training_set=True)
        self.valid = self.tokenize(os.path.join(path2))
        self.test = self.tokenize(os.path.join(path3))

    def tokenize(self, path, training_set=False):
        """Tokenizes a text file."""
        #assert os.path.exists(path)
        with open(path, path2, path3) as fin:
            num_lines = sum(1 for _ in fin.readlines())
        with open(path, path2, path3, 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
            words = []
            for i, line in enumerate(tqdm(f, total=num_lines)):
                if self.max_lines > 0 and i > self.max_lines:
                    break
                line = line.strip()
                if not line:
                    continue  # Skip empty lines.
                elif line.startswith('='):
                    continue  # Skip headers.
                else:
                    sentence = (self.order - 1) * [SOS] + \
                        [process(word, self.lower) for word in line.split()] + [EOS]
                    if training_set:
                        words.extend(sentence)
                        self.vocab.update(sentence)
                    else:
                        sentence = [word if word in self.vocab else UNK for word in sentence]
                        words.extend(sentence)
        return words


if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = 'C://Users//supre//Documents//Python Programme//kenlm//wikitext-2//wiki.train.tokens'
    path2 = 'C://Users//supre//Documents//Python Programme//kenlm//wikitext-2//wiki.valid.tokens'
    path3 = 'C://Users//supre//Documents//Python Programme//kenlm//wikitext-2//wiki.test.tokens'
    corpus = Corpus(path, order=3)
    print(len(corpus.test))
    print(corpus.test[:100])
```

Thank's for every help and suggestion in advance:)

Comment: The constructor waits for them, and you don't pass them when instanciating the Corpus

Comment: ok thank you very very much

Comment: "I've declared the positional arguments ``path2`` and  ``path3``" You've declared *two variables* with that name. The constructor cannot guess that these are meant to be the arguments.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The name of the arguments in the constructor has nothing related to the name of the variables you pass to it, so you need to pass them all, there is no mechanism of taking the same-name variables

```
class Corpus(object):
    def __init__(self, path, path2, path3, order, lower=False, max_lines=-1):
        self.order = order
        self.lower = lower
        self.max_lines = max_lines
        self.vocab = set()
        self.train = self.tokenize(path, training_set=True)
        self.valid = self.tokenize(path2)
        self.test = self.tokenize(path3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pa = 'C://Users//...//kenlm//wikitext-2//wiki.train.tokens'
    pa2 = 'C://Users//...//kenlm//wikitext-2//wiki.valid.tokens'
    pa3 = 'C://Users//...//kenlm//wikitext-2//wiki.test.tokens'

   corpus = Corpus(pa, pa2, pa3, order=3)
```

---

Also `os.path.join` with 1 variable does nothing special

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass these parameters when calling an object of class `Corpus`.
`corpus = Corpus(path, path2, path3, order=3)`